# How do do sump pump installation with trenching

Tags: sump-pump, crawlspace

Given the estimates i have been provided, I am going to try to do it myself. Here is what i came up with as the step by step method

1. Dig a trench (4”x6”) along foundation.
2. Dig a 24” sump pit for putting the basin
3. Make sure the trench is sloping so that the water flows towards the basin
4. Put Landscaping cloth in the trench
5. Put perforated pipe with holes facing down in the trench
6. Wrap the cloth around the pipe
7. Fill it with river gravel
8. Also, fill the sump pit with river gravel around the basin
9. Now, do the basic plumbing to with backflow to push the water in the cement gutter outside home.

I am confused about the following. Can you please help me understand these.

1. What to do with the ends. How to cap the end of perforated pipe?
2. Do I need to put river gravel in the trench and then put pipe and then fill again with gravel?
3. Does each sump pump need a dedicated circuit of 20Amp?
4. Do I need to perforate the basin from bottom

Please feel free to modify my steps and let me know if I am going wrong somewhere

Comment: If you have multiple pumps yes, put each on its own circuit... if one ever fails catastrophically and throws the breaker you don’t want it turning off others that are still good.

Comment: I wanted to know how much amperage each pump is required to have. I need 2 pumps, one on each corner of the house. I was thinking of using existing circuits for both of them. First pump on existing AC circuit,  Second pump on existing electric fireplace circuit. For both of these the wires are already in the crawl space. All i need is a junction box and GFCI outlet.